# Devise + Omniauth + Google: CSRF Detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

We have a web application that uses devise for user authentication, and omniauth in order to connect social media accounts to a user's account - BUT not allow authentication into our application with those social media accounts.

We are running into a situation where an already-signed-up user (numerous) is attempting to add a social media account to their profile, but my theory is that devise is picking up on the presence of the omniauth params within the request and trying to authenticate.  The user is then redirected to the signin URL (without the omniauth params) and they are authenticated, but adding the social media account fails because of this.

FWIW, this behavior is inconsistent.  Sometimes users are successfully able to add an account and others they are not (even with the exact same account).

How do you recommend using devise + omniauth in this scenario?

I'm happy to provide additional info, but want to make sure the information I provide is relevant as to not inundate this ticket with unnecessary info.  Also have researched this extensively for days - I've determined that devise is definitely causing this redirect and thus is why I'm posting here.

Gems

```
devise (3.5.2)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.6)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.0)
```

Comment: Did you add any smart forwarding? I've never done what you're trying to do (use omni auth to do social media stuff, but not auth). I'm willing to bet that there are functions that are attempting to authenticate which you will need to 'overload' so that they don't work when 'authenticating social media'

Comment: You would happen to be inheriting your OmniAuth callbacks controller from `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`?

Comment: Also devise won't actually pickup on any request except the ones where the request path happen to match the routes assigned to devise. I'm guessing what is happening instead is that they are hitting a callback action which requires authentication which is causing the user to be redirected to the sign in. Does the sign in redirect occur before they are forwarded to the auth provider or after?

Comment: Also please add your routes and callbacks controller. Too much info is preferable to too little.